# How to use one content-type as options for another content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to find a way to use one content-type's field as a list of options for another content-type.

For example, I'm trying to build an image slider for a specific product category. So on the one hand I would have a content-type "product category" which contains all categories, and on the other hand I would have my "product photo" content-type which would contain the image, title, alt text and a select dropdown with all product categories (directly loaded from the 'product category' content).

This way, it would also be possible for me to add a 'product category' to the main 'basic page' content pages and use that for the view which builds the photoslider, making it really easy to add a overview page to my website for a certain product category, while still keeping everything dynamics (so I don't have to fiddle with my views once the site is up and running).

Does anyone here know how to do that?

Comment: You could use a taxonomy.

Comment: Thats a very good solution actually.. you should post it as a question so I can give you the points, since you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Taxonomy is a common solution in Drupal to represent simple or nested categorizations.

Taxonomy vocabularies are very flexible and can also be combined with [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) or similar modules to handle breadcrumbs, menu entries or permissions.

However you should be aware that by default each taxonomy term has its own additional menu entry.

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy is definitely the way to go.  It's a Drupal 6 walkthrough but the example at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBdVW7fC2Tg should be helpful.  Taxonomy + Views + Pathauto and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your great tutorial.. it's exactly what I found after Jantimon pointed me in the right direction.